# SQL Developer 4 and Oracle 12c - Not finding Foreign keys when importing model from data dictionary

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working with Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production on CentOS Linux and Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 4.0.1.836 on Windows (64-bit). (Same result using SQL Developer 4.1.1.19.59).

I am attempting to import a model from the data dictionary using the "HR" schema by following these steps: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldevdm/r20/updatedb/UpdateDB.html

After the schema is imported, I receive the following log:

```
    Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 4.0.1.836
    Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler Import Log
    Date and Time: 2015-09-15 10:03:22 EDT
    Design Name: Untitled_1
    RDBMS : Oracle Database 12c
    All Statements:         10
    Imported Statements:    10
    Failed Statements:   0
    Not Recognized Statements: 0
```

However the resulting model has no foreign key constraints and thus no relationships between the entitles (tables) in the diagram.

ETA: I see there are foreign keys defined on the tables:

```
SELECT owner, constraint_name, constraint_type
FROM user_constraints;

OWNER   CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE
HR      COUNTR_REG_FK   R
HR      LOC_C_ID_FK     R
HR      DEPT_LOC_FK     R
HR      JHIST_DEPT_FK   R
HR      EMP_DEPT_FK     R
HR      JHIST_JOB_FK    R
HR      EMP_JOB_FK      R
HR      JHIST_EMP_FK    R
HR      DEPT_MGR_FK     R
HR      EMP_MANAGER_FK  R
etc.
```

I also tried the "Discover Foreign Keys" function but it still fails to show any foreign keys.

I know I have been able to do this successfully with Oracle11g databases.

ETA: The pluggable database was altered to allow large varchar columns.

Any suggestions on getting this to work?

As a corollary to this (might be related) if I point to the HR schema in the database and run the Database Export wizard, the resulting DDL sql script has no statements for foreign keys in it.

Comment: Are you certain that foreign key constraints are defined on the tables?  Try selecting from user_constraints where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE' and contraint_type = 'R'

Comment: Yes-thanks-just updated question with that info.

Comment: Just an update-  looks like this is an issue with the data dictionary on the server (ALL_CONSTRAINTS view does not seem to be working properly)  and may not be related to SQL Developer. I will update once I figure out what is going on at the server side.